# How to transfer set of text from file to file using two identifiers using PHP?

Tags: php, file, string

This code below can migrate the two variables from one file into the other.

```
<?php
$file = 'somefile.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = fopen($file,'a');
// Append a new person to the file
$firstname .= "aiden\n";
$secondname .= "dawn\n";
$currentContent = file_get_contents($file);
// Write the contents back to the file
$fileFound = 'people.txt';
$newFile = fopen($fileFound,'a');
//if $current and $nextcurrent is found in the somefile.txt it will transfer the content to people.txt
if (strpos($currentContent,$firstname) !== 0)
{
if (strpos($currentContent,$secondname) !== 0)
{
    fwrite($newFile, $currentContent."\n");
    } // endif
}// endif
?>
```

The next problem is, how am i able to migrate the texts from identifier one up to identifiers two?
I guess I'll have to use *substr* or a *strrpos* string here.
Help Please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding the problem but looks like you're trying to include anything between 'aiden' and 'dawn' from a file and write the result into a new file.

Give a shot for this one

```
$firstIdentifier = 'aiden';
$secondIdentifier = 'dawn';
$currentContent = str_replace("\n", "", file_get_contents('sourcefile.txt'));
$pattern = '/('.$firstIdentifier.')(.+?)('.$secondIdentifier.')/'; 

//get all text between the two identifiers, and include the identifiers in the match result
preg_match_all($pattern, $currentContent , $matches);

//stick them together with space delimiter
$contentOfNewFile = implode(" ",$matches[0]);

//save to a new file
$newFile = fopen('destinationFile.txt','a');
fwrite($newFile, $contentOfNewFile);
```

Comment: the destination.txt does not contain any texts. :(

Comment: It works on my side. My sourcefile.txt contains : "aidenhellodawn  w245345 sdgdfty 34534rtsdfg sdgd345 aidenworlddawn" , destinationFile.txt contains after running the script "aidenhellodawn aidenworlddawn"

Comment: i have try to run again the code, it work this time. Since the last time i run this, the sourceFile.txt contains: aiden (newline) some text here (newline) dawn

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need `fopen` when you are using `file_get_contents`
2. Instead of using a delimiter I'd suggest you just serialize your variables

In file 1:

```
file_put_contents('somefile.txt',serialize(array($firstname,$lastname)));
```

In file 2:

```
list($firstname,$lastname) = unserialize(file_get_contents('somefile.txt'))
```